# unique_ptr reference to deleted function when implementing interface

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have the following code, which is being built using the MSVC2013 toolchain, C++11 (Old stuff a function of work constraints):

```
template<class T>
class AbstractWrappedQueue {
public:
    virtual bool empty() = 0;
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
    virtual void push(T& value) = 0;
    virtual void push(T&& value) = 0;
    virtual T pop() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class WrappedQueue // : public AbstractWrappedQueue<T>
{
private:
    std::queue<T> q;
public:
    WrappedQueue() {}
    ~WrappedQueue() {}
    bool empty() { return q.empty(); }
    size_t size() { return q.size(); }
    void push(T& p) { q.push(p); }
    void push(T&& p) { q.push(std::move(p)); }
    T pop() {
        T r = std::move(q.front());
        q.pop();
        return r;
    }
};

WrappedQueue<std::unique_ptr<int>> ptr;
```

As long as `WrappedQueue` stands alone, the class, and it's functionality, plays with `unique_ptr`s without a problem.  However, should it implement the `AbstractWrappedQueue` interface (i.e., uncomment the `: AbstractWrappedQueue<T>` part of the class definition, then I get the following error:

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function.
```

I would not expect the application of my interface to cause a situation where an attempt to copy a `unique_ptr` might occur.  Why is this occurring?  What can be done to prevent it (aside from simply not using the interface)?

Comment: Missing virtual destructor.

Comment: "_I would not expect the application of my interface to cause a situation where an attempt to copy a `unique_ptr` might occur_" What do you expect happens, when you call `void push(T& p) { q.push(p); }`, where `T = std::unique_ptr<int>`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Per [std::queue's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/push), the push accepts parameters by reference, so not a copy.

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie That same documentation states "_Effectively calls c.push_back(value)_". The default container for [`std::queue<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is [`std::deque<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) of which states "_The new element is initialized as a copy of value._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this function:

```
void push(T& p) { q.push(p); }
```

This copies `p`, and if `p` is a `std::unique_ptr<int>`, that's not going to work - it's not copyable.

If you *just* have `WrappedQueue<T>`, non-`virtual` member functions of class templates are never instantiated until they're actually used. So this is not an error until somebody actually tries to `push` an lvalue. This is why `std::vector<T>::push_back(T const&)` can exist and yet allow you to have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` anyway. This is fine - it's only an error when you try to do something that is obviously wrong.

However, once you have `AbstractWrappedQueue<T>` - that has virtual member functions, and there the rule is more fuzzy: [[temp.inst]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#10.sentence-2):

> It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.

Your implementation is instantiating it anyway - and that function is ill-formed for `T=std::unique_ptr<int>`. Hence the problem.

You can prevent it by either not having that virtual function, or only using copyable types.

---

Side-note: you probably want `push(T const&)`, not `push(T&)`.